# data synchronization between redis and mysql

Tags: mysql, redis

I changed the data on redis, wanted to synchronize it to mysql periodically, how do I do it? what are the solutions, the tools?
at the same time, data no found on redis, how to synchronize from mysql to redis?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080557/whats-the-best-strategy-to-sync-redis-data-to-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best strategy to sync Redis data to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080557/whats-the-best-strategy-to-sync-redis-data-to-mysql)